# How to change definer of function in MYSQL - Linux?

Tags: mysql, linux, function

I know there are answers for changing definer of **procedure** but no answer for changing definer of function.

I want to change definer from `'root@localhost' to 'root@%'.`

Is there any way to change definer of function in MYSQL in Linux?

Comment: What do you use in backend? Is it PHP maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You can't alter DEFINER in a FUNCTION.

You can use SHOW CREATE, alter the definer in the result, DROP old function and CREATE new function with altered definer in create statement.

[Example with PHP](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/changing-definer-mysql-stored-routines-etc).

Comment: so there is no script like we do it for procedures??:  **UPDATE `mysql`.`proc` p SET definer = 'root@%' WHERE definer='root@localhost'**

Comment: As far as I know, unfortunately no.